# jQuery return links false if it has li has children li

Tags: jquery

i have unordered list i wrote a jQuery code to disable the link if its li has children (ul li), but its not working

jQuery code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.sidebarnew > ul > li > a').click( function(){
        maincat = $(this).parent();
        if (maincat.children('li').length){
            maincat.find('>a')(function(){
                return false;
                });
            }
      });

   });
```

HTML

```
    <div class="sidebarnew">
  <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="products.php?category_id=1">Products
    <i class="icon-angle-down float-right"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li> 
        <a href="products.php?category_id=3">Outdoor Furniture</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> 
    <a href="products.php?category_id=27">New Cat
    <i class="icon-angle-down float-right"></i></a>
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebarnew > ul > li').has('li').children('a').click(function () {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dbzLv6qq/)

---

Or the simplified version

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebarnew > ul > li:has(li) > a').click(function () {
        return false;
    });
});
```